# assurer vs s'assurer

Tags: usage

Je mélange souvent ces deux verbes et j’ai des difficultés de les distinguer.  Peut-on m’expliquer leur différence ?

Je sais que l’on dit :

```
Après la réparation, **j’assure** que la chaudière s'allumera sans problème.
```

> Est-ce vous pouvez **vous assurer** que les étudiants se comporteront bien
>   pendant la visite de président ?

En général, on utilise **« assurer »** dans le sens de **« garantir »** et **« s’assurer »** est utilisé pour décrire une assurance.

Quelqu'un peut-il me donner une explication plus précise ?

Answer (score 3):

Je pense que tu peux remplacer le verbe « s’assurer » par « vérifier» et comme tu as dis « assurer » par « garantir ». Donc on peut remplacer :

> Après la réparation, je garantis que la chaudière s'allumera sans problème.
>
> Est-ce vous pouvez vérifier que les étudiants se comportent bien pendant la visite du président ?

« assurer » signifie que l’on donne donc une garantie/assurance sur quelque chose. Alors que « s’assurer » veux dire que l’on cherche a être sûr de quelque chose donc on recherche une assurance.

Comment: Merci.  Je me rends compte qu’il y a d’autres mots qu’on peut utiliser, mais en concernant les deux que j’ai mentionnés, est-ce que mes exemples sont corrects ?

Comment: Ton utilisation de ces verbes est tout a fait correcte. Sauf si dans la premiere phrase tu voulais dire que tu vérifies que la chaudière fonctionne bien car dans ce cas il faut dire : «Après la réparation, je **m**’assure que la chaudière s’allumera sans problème. »

Answer (score 2):

S'assurer, c'est faire en sorte que quelque chose se passe comme prévu, vérifier la véracité de quelque chose ou prendre les mesures pour réduire les risques ou les conséquences d'une événement qui peut nous concerner directement.

> Assure-toi de son départ à l'heure. (*make sure he leaves on time*)
>
> Je m'assure que le gaz est bien fermé. (*I make sure the gas supply is shut off*)
>
> Je m'assure contre l'incendie de ma maison. (*I take a fire insurance for my house*)

Assurer, c'est prendre en charge ces mesures ou faire quelque chose pour quelqu'un ou quelque chose d'autre.

> J'assure ma maison contre l'incendie. (*I insure my house against fire damages*)
>
> J'assure mes amis de mon soutien sans faille. (*I assure my friends about my full support*)
>
> J'espère qu'il a assuré ses arrières ! (*I hope he protected his back*)
>
> Le double-vitrage assure une protection contre le bruit. (*The double glazing provides noise protection*)

Voici les formes correctes des deux phrases proposées, avec quatre variantes pour la première en fonction du sens attendu :

> *Après la réparation, **je m’assure** que la chaudière s'allumera sans problème.* (I check...)
>
> *Après la réparation, **j’assure** que la chaudière s'allumera sans problème.* (I promise...)
>
> *Après la réparation, **on m'assure** que la chaudière s'allumera sans problème.* (I'm told...)
>
> *Après la réparation, **je suis assuré** que la chaudière s'allumera sans problème.* (I'm sure...)
>
> *Est-ce **que** vous pouvez vous assurer que les étudiants se comporteront bien pendant la visite de président ?* (make sure)

Answer (score 1):

je pense que pour ne plus confondre les deux verbes, il vaut mieux se dire que c'est le même verbe (assurer) utilisé avec un pronom personnel réfléchi (ou pas).

Bref,

```
s'assurer = assurer soi-même
```

This works quite well with the primary meaning of "assurer", that is "making sure". If you make yourself sure of something, then you verify it can be trusted.

Les deux versions peuvent également s'utiliser dans le cas d'une assurance:

```
Je me suis assuré contre l'incendie = j'ai contracté une assurance contre l'incendie. (C'est un petit abus de langage car c'est la maison qui est assurée et non moi-même, mais cela se dit)

Ma maison est assurée contre l'incendie.
```